# Putting indices on all columns of a read only table

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have a table in a database that will be generated from the start and probably never be written to again. Even if it were ever written to, it'll be in the form of batch processes run during a release, and write time is not important at all.

It's a relatively large table with about 80k rows and maybe about 10-12 columns.

The application is likely to retrieve data from this table often.

I was thinking, since it'll never be written to again, should I just put indices on all the columns? That way it'll always be quick to read no matter what type of query I form?

Is this a good idea? Is there any downside to this I should be aware of?

Comment: Not necessarily: if you have columns with very low selectivity, like a "Sex" column which has only two or three possible values, an index will only be overhead, never be used, and thus totally useless. Also: depending on your query patterns, it might be better to create a select few wider indices (including multiple columns) rather than lots of small (one column) indices. But that depends on your queries (and your table structure)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that each index does require some (a relatively small amount of) storage space. If you're tight for space this could matter. Exactly how much impact this might make may depend on which DB you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the table.  If all of the columns will be used in search criteria, then it is not unreasonable to put indexes on them all.  That is fairly unlikely though.  Also, there may be compound (multi-column) indexes that would be more beneficial than some of the simple (single-column) indexes.

Finally, the query optimizer will have to review all the indexes that are present on the table when evaluating how answer queries.  It is hard to say when this becomes a measurable overhead, but more indexes takes more time.

So, given the static nature of the table you describe, it is reasonable to index it more heavily than you might a more dynamic table.  Indexing every column is probably not sensible.  Choosing carefully which compound indexes to add may be important too.

Answer (score 0):

**Choose indexes for a table based on the queries you run against that table.**

Indexes you never need for any query are just wasted space.

Individual indexes on each column isn't the full set of indexes possible.  You also can make multi-column indexes (i.e. compound indexes), and these can be important for optimizing certain queries.  The order of columns in a compound index matters.

SQL Server 2008 supports only 999 nonclustered indexes per table, so if you try to create all possible indexes on a table of more than a few columns, you will reach the limit.

Sorry, but you actually need to learn some things before you can optimize effectively.  If it were simply a matter of indexing every column, then the RDBMS would do this by default.